# using map() with dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary.

```
prices = {'n': 99, 'a': 99, 'c': 147}
```

using map () I need to receive new dictionary :

```
def formula(value):
    value = value -value * 0.05
    return value
```

```
new_prices = dict(map(formula, prices.values()))
```

but it doesn't work

```
TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
```

solving my code using `map()`:

```
new_prices = {'n': 94.05, 'a': 94.05, 'c': 139.65}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a homework question.

Comment: Homework questions are not, in and of themselves, off-topic.

Comment: `map` is designed to work on *all* iterables; you need to work with an iterable with a specific structure. That means not using `map`, or mapping a different function over a different iterator.

Answer (score 7):

you can do this using `zip` and `map`

```
new_prices = dict(zip(prices, map(formula, prices.values())))
```

Comment: No need to call `prices.keys()`; `zip` calls `iter` on each argument internally, and `iter(prices)` yields the keys as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Use [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
new_prices = {k: formula(prices[k]) for k in prices}
print(new_prices)
# {'n': 94.05, 'a': 94.05, 'c': 139.65}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! But I need to solve it without 'for' using map

Answer (score 1):

Use `map()` with a helper `lambda` to create new dict

```
new_prices = dict(map(lambda item: (item[0], formula(item[1])), prices.items()))
```

output:

```
{'n': 94.05, 'a': 94.05, 'c': 139.65}
```

Comment: thnx! but can I  solve it without using  lambda?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid lambda expressions?

Comment: @JayPeerachai Same as my solution I deleted it since you posted it before me.

Answer (score 0):

First option (using a dict comprehension):

```
    prices = {'n': 99, 'a': 99, 'c': 147}
    
    
    def formula(value):
        value = value -value * 0.05
        return value

    #Using a dict comprehension and .items() [giving you key value tuples] instead of map()
    new_prices = {k: formula(v) for k, v in prices.items()}
    
    print(new_prices)
    # {'n': 94.05, 'a': 94.05, 'c': 139.65}
```

Second option (using map and defining the formula slightly differently [tuple as input]):

```
    #Define the formula with a key value pair (tuple) as input and return value
    def f_items(items):
        value = items[1] - items[1] * 0.05
        return items[0], value
    
    
    new_prices = dict(map(f_items, prices.items()))
    
    print(new_prices)
    # {'n': 94.05, 'a': 94.05, 'c': 139.65}
```

Answer (score -2):

When you create a `map`, you get a `map` object. It's nice to have an helper function to iterate through this object.

```
def print_results(map_object):
    for i in map_object:
        print(i)

def formula(value):
    return value * 0.95 # one-liner

m = map(formula, prices.values())

print_results(m)

# output
94.05
94.05
139.65
```

Comment: The original question asks to create a new dict, not just the list of new values.